# Setting up i2c on Raspberry Pi for C?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, i2c

I'm setting up i2c for an Application written in C, but I've not been able to find any how-to's for it. I'm running a model-b Raspberry Pi on Debian 6 with LXDE. Can anybody show me how to set up i2c so I can use it in a C Application?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: In a month or two I need this too. Would be kind if I would find a how-to of you.

Comment: Sounds pretty good! Perhaps you could describe your actions? @ManuelSchneid3r

Comment: I want to write some cronjobs getting temperatures from TI sensors and save them in a db. php reads them out. In the end it is heating supervising rPi.

Comment: The Raspbian distro worked out of the box for me. I tried the Arch distro for Pi, but `modprobe i2c-bcm2708` doesn't add anything to `lsmod`. The same command on Raspbian works, provided you remove it from the blacklist.

If you can `i2cdetect` then your C program will work; otherwise, the drivers aren't set up properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking for similar information and I found a couple of i2c tutorials, one in [adafruit tutorials](http://learn.adafruit.com/category/raspberry-pi) and the other in [Guy Carpenter's Gaugette blog](http://guy.carpenter.id.au/gaugette/).  I'm not yet at the stage of actually using it so I can't vouch for their completeness but they seem to be a good start.

- [Configuring Your Pi for I2C](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-servo-driver-with-raspberry-pi/configuring-your-pi-for-i2c)
- [Analog Gauges Using I²C on the Raspberry Pi](http://guy.carpenter.id.au/gaugette/blog/2012/09/14/i2c-with-raspberry-pi/)
- [I2C Installation for Raspberry Pi](http://www.skpang.co.uk/blog/archives/575).  I think this is only necessary if not using AdaFruit's [Occidentalis](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-educational-linux-distro/overview) release which has it included.

Comment: yeah, but how do I set up the libraries? That's my only trouble with this.

Comment: Updated with the "I2C installation" link I hope will help.

Comment: Note that the Analog Gauge article posted by TheDuke links to the following C code which illustrates the i2c library in use: https://gist.github.com/guyc/3735664

Answer (score 0):

try this :

[C GPIO Interface library for the Raspberry Pi](http://wiringpi.com/)

It offers API for handling GPIO port on Raspberry, including dedicated functions for I2C interface. I've been using this to read measurements from temperature sensor and it works perfect (STCN75 connected to RPi rev. B).

You can find examples and instructions on author's website. Project is maintained and updated frequently on public Git repo.